# Not able to get date based on current locale

Tags: ios, swift, localization, nsdateformatter

I’m populating month and date in a tableview. I have the app supporting France language also along with English. But I’m not able to get the months in France language when I change the locale to French. It’s getting reflected only once I launch the app again and not immediately after I change the language within the app.

This is what I have tried in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`…

```
let dic = myArray[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary
var utcTime = "\(dic["Due_Date"]!)"

self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss”

let currentLanguage = …. (Correctly gives ‘en’ OR ‘fr')
self.dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: currentLanguage)

self.dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC”)

if let date = dateFormatter.date(from:utcTime) {
             
   let monthInt = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date)
   dayInt = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: date)
            
   let yearInt = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: date)
   let monthStr = Calendar.current.monthSymbols[monthInt-1]
   print(monthStr, dayInt).  //If the current language is ‘fr’ the month is printed here in English. It changes back to French only after I launch the app again

}
```

EDIT: This is how I changed the language within the app..

There is a class like so...

```
let APPLE_LANGUAGE_KEY = "AppleLanguages"

class TheLanguage {
    
    class func currentAppleLanguage() -> String{
        let userdef = UserDefaults.standard
        let langArray = userdef.object(forKey: APPLE_LANGUAGE_KEY) as! NSArray
        let current = langArray.firstObject as! String
        return current
    }
    

    class func setAppleLAnguageTo(lang: String) {
        let userdef = UserDefaults.standard
        userdef.set([lang,currentAppleLanguage()], forKey: APPLE_LANGUAGE_KEY)
        userdef.synchronize()
    }
}
```

And I get the current language like so...

`let currentLanguage = TheLanguage.currentAppleLanguage()`

Comment: How did you change the language within the app? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Have edited the question showing how I changed the language within the app..@Sweeper

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

***monthSymbols:**
A list of months in this calendar, localized to the Calendar’s locale.*

So I guess you need to change the calendar's locale to the one the user has selected.

**Edit:**

But, if you just need the month name from a given date (don't known what type dueDate is in your example) you can use this code:

```
let dueDate = Date()

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "LLLL"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr")

let month = dateFormatter.string(from: dueDate)
```

Comment: I tried changing the calendar locale also. But it's not working